# Solving wide code

Tags: discussion, code-length

This SE site has a lot of long code postings. Usually these are just copy pasted from actual source code.

The maximum line width before a horizontal scrollbar appears, seems to be only 80 characters. Times when 80 was considered an optimal maximum line width are long gone.

For other SE sites, I feel it's the posters duty to make sure the code is readable, and only the necessary code is presented. For Code Review I do feel you should be able to just post code without having to edit it for better viewing.

Several proposals have already been done:

- [A stack exchange brand
  'pastebin'.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70043/157047)
- [Viewing code in a new window.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23611/157047)
- [Collapsible code blocks.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/2254)

Perhaps a simple or intelligent wordwrap is also suitable. Consider the revision of [this question I posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1070/2254) as something I would like to see automated.

UPDATE:

I forgot to mention, couldn't a different column layout work as well? Where the code/question part resizes freely to the remaining space, and only the right column is fixed?

Comment: Currently the whole page is fixed-width. The site layout would have to change to make the question area wider. Wordwrap is an idea...

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I can really think of is making the font smaller for the moment. edit: *this is done*.

It is true that we expect more code here than on, say, Stack Overflow .. but even for a code review, you should strive to provide *just the relevant* code and not force people to read reams of your code to get to the "good bits".

A great code review request is scoped to the correct amount of code.

A bad code review request is dumping thousands of lines of code in people's laps and expecting them to critique it for you.

Comment: Thanks, that at least already allows 12 more characters in width. :)

Comment: That does assume that you know what is and is not the relevant/correct amount of code... I can't speak for anyone else, but if I can get that far I can usually work it out myself. The real problem comes when I can't find where the real problem is.