# Should font-size for question text and code blocks be the same?

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface, formatting

On StackOverflow the the font-size for text and code appears to be the same, but on CodeReview they're noticeably different.

It's a bit of an annoyance, because when the text font size is set to my preference (about 10pt.), the code appears to be 8pt. To read the code blocks comfortably, I have to adjust page zoom to make the text appear larger than I would like.

The effect becomes even more pronounced when inline code formatting is used in adjacency to a code block. Here's an example from one of my questions:

[image]

Does anyone else find this annoying? Is this something that should be changed?

Comment: The font size in the code blocks on CR [was reduced some time ago](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/229/1432) to better fit the larger blocks of code expected here.

Comment: @BrianReichle If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was implemented [as a partial quick-fix](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/229/2254) to [a discussion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/2254) I started a while back.

After this change, I found the average code samples a lot more readable, so I would argue to keep this change. However, more suitable (but more difficult) solutions can still be considered, which is why I didn't accept Jeff's answer.

Most modern web browser allow easy up and downscaling (e.g. ctrl + and ctrl -), which seems to be a more suitable solution for you.